# Missing required parameters for [Route: reviews.show] (from controller)

Tags: laravel, view

i want to route a new page from controller, i am getting data successfully when passing in route but getting error.

here is my particular part of controller -

```
 $use = User::find($user->id);
        $pos = posts::find($post->id);
        //dd($user1, $post1);
        return redirect()->route('reviews.show', $pos, $use);
```

in web.php part -

```
Route::get('p/{posts}/review/{user}','ReviewController@show')->name('reviews.show');
```

in show method -

```
 public function show($posts, $user)
    {
        return view('posts.reviews.reviewshow', ['posts' => $posts], ['user' => $user]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass 2 paramters to a route you send them as Array

```php
return redirect()->route('reviews.show', [ $pos, $use ]);
```

This is your issue

Answer (score 2):

You have to use like this

```
return redirect()->route('reviews.show', ['posts' => $pos, 'user' => $use]);
```

Answer (score 2):

`route()` calls in general take URL parameters as associative array. You are using helper function for it, but it still applies.

```
redirect()->route('reviews.show', ['posts' => $pos, 'user' => $use]);
```

Comment: thanks fixed. but i didn't found it in laravel documentation

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/redirects#redirecting-named-routes